# How to get piped output in color?

Tags: shell, csh, more

I am using FreeBSD with the csh shell. 
As an example, in the terminal / screen I get color output for ls (eg. ls -lGs). But when I pipe it through more (eg ls -lGs | more) the output has no colour.
Is there a way to have more also display color?

Comment: In Ubuntu `ls` has the `--color` option, and `ls --color=always` retains colouring when output is redirected.

Comment: You put me on the right track, I will make an answer for the community.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem in two steps.

First I set the environment varable CLICOLOR_FORCE in .cshrc to force output other then to TERM to also use colors, eg:

```
CLICOLOR_FORCE 1
```

more has a command line option -R to output color sequences.

> ```
>    -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
>           Like  -r,  but  only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in
>           "raw" form.  Unlike -r, the screen appearance is maintained cor-
>           rectly  in  most  cases.   ANSI  "color"  escape  sequences  are
>           sequences of the form:
> ```

These two combined gave me the desired results, so

```
ls -lGs | more -R
```

now displays the output in color.

Comment: Glad you found a solution: for the record, your answer doesn't work with my configuration of Ubuntu/`bash` with GNU `ls`, but this is a long way from FreeBSD/`csh`, so it's not surprising. In my case `more` has no `-R` option, but it works without.

Comment: Should I add the FreeBSD tag to the question? It might work on other systems... They question and answer should be clear enough.

Comment: I'm not sure what to advise: I have seen reference to `CLICOLOR_FORCE` on other systems, and my comments should help when your solution doesn't work. I have no idea how many people will come upon this solution by searching on the tag, rather than the title, but I suspect not many.